# Shiny App doesn't work while accessing on remote computer

Tags: r, shiny, remote-desktop

I am trying to run a ShinyApp via R studio. The R Studio is on my work computer and I am accessing it from my home computer via remote access.

I tried changing the host argument in runApp to "0.0.0.0" (as suggested:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568434/cannot-connect-remotely-to-shiny-server-and-get-r-app-working-properly)  )
and even then all i get is a dark blank screen.

Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a few colleagues at work, I figured that there could be an issue with accessing the shiny output via R studio in built browser when accessing it remotely.
The workaround which works for me is to open a new browser via
runApp(shinyobject<-shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser=T)